# I opened two bounties and got only unhelpful answers

Tags: discussion, bounty

Basically as the title. The system does not work for me and I wasted some of my reputation for nothing. I am not amused.

Is there anything I could do?

Do I understand the help correctly that my bounty is effectively wasted? I won't award the bounty to the provided answers (one per question) and as long the meta effect won't create unnecessary upvotes there will be no automatic awarding too.

Comment: "Is there anything I could do?" is a rather vague question. What is your desired outcome? A refund on the bounties?

Comment: If you want guaranteed results, you'll have to hire a consultant. Here, we allow you to gamble free fake internet points to attempt to attract free answers. It works pretty well, and if it doesn't you only lose some free fake internet points. You might not be amused, but you also shouldn't be upset.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Those questions are for open source software, therefore I am not willing to paying anything. I do not even expect to ever see a thank you for my work.

Comment: People pay consultants to support and modify open-source software all the time.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk but only if you are a big company and not a single developer. In my mind it should be give and take and the "money" is "reputation", when this is not the case then the reputation is pointless.

Comment: @F1Krazy I just want get some help. The "lost" reputation including the downvotes are just loosing useless points. The fact that I only got downvotes is somehow a prove for me that this platform became very toxic IMHO or even the upvotes for bad answers just to annoy me. (I'm well aware that that on meta downvotes are an indicator of disagree). Right now I am already thinking to sunset my account. This platform seems to be a huge waste of time for me. So bad several years ago I enjoyed this platform a lot.

Comment: The site will never cease to be of use to you because it will remain to be in the top 10 search results of your favourite search engine. Probably multiple times. That was the goal you were supposed to be helping to fulfil all those years where you were hoarding useless reputation points. It worked. And as a result, asking questions has now become infinitely harder. Cause and effect.

Comment: Seeing as the bounties are now applied automatically, this case is basically closed :D

Comment: Be glad of what you got, rather than being sorry for what you did **not** get. A couple of 'unhelpful' answers is certainly better than no answers at all.

Answer (score 45):

When applying a bounty, you pay rep for *visibility*.

You're not paying for answers. There's no way to guarantee (good) answers.

So yes, that is the system working as intended. Your questions got more visibility, and thus more answers.

> I wasted some of my reputation for nothing.

No, you got 2 answers.

- [The first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78117316/1835379) tells you what you want is possible, but deprecated, and links you to the modern replacement.
- [The second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78122809/1835379) is an attempt at answering your question. It may not be complete, but then again, your question didn't mention you looked into that.

That's certainly not "nothing". I think it's rather disingenuous to *hope* those answers don't get the required 2 upvotes to automatically get 50% of the bounty.

Comment: Hell it's even possible for the extra eyeballs on a bad question to lose a user more rep than the bounty will.  `from StreisandEffect import *`

Comment: Well that just proofs how broken this platform is

Comment: *Proves. And no. It just proves that you didn't look into how this works.

Comment: If you believe that the purpose of the platform is that you can come in and get personalized assistance with a coding problem, then yes, it's completely broken. However, **that understanding is completely incorrect**. The purpose of the platform is to build a high quality reference library, collaboratively.